# Is it possible to split a sata connection

Tags: sata, connection, data-transfer, splitter

I have a computer that I am using for testing custom windows images, and I have needed to access the physical ssd in it a lot, so I wanted to know if there was just a way to split the sata connection, to access the drive when the computer is offline easily.

Comment: No; What you want is not possible.

Comment: @Ramhound That should be an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @TilmanSchmidt - I see way to turn my comment into an answer.

Answer (score 0):

### Install Hot Swap Bay

You are talking about splitting but what you are asking about is a way to access the SSD easily from the outside so you dont need to open the case and disconnect/reconnect the drive.

Install a Hot-Swap Hard Drive Bay for 2.5" SATA SSD / HDD in one of your front 3.5" or 5.25" bays.  Similar to installing a DVD Burner.

Uses the same connectors that you would use internally to connect the drive but instead they connect to the caddy.

Here is an example from Startec https://www.startech.com/en-us/hdd/s251bu31rem that can work as an internal bay using the SATA cables or a portable USB enclosure.